# Replacement value not working?

Tags: python, string, python-itertools

So I've got a try/except block set up, which will go through a database dependent on certain conditions:

```
try:
    for searchnumber in itertools.count(0):
        print searchnumber
        c.execute("""SELECT words from searchterms where onstate = 1 AND progid = %d;""") % searchnumber
        searchterms = (c.fetchall())
        searchterms = [",".join(x) for x in searchterms]
        print searchterms
except:
    pass
```

For some reason, it isn't iterating on progid, in fact, it isn't even getting the first value assigned to it (0). Why would this be? As far as I know, %d should be replaced by the integer value of searchnumber

Comment: I'm confused by the `% searchnumber` *outside* the `c.execute()` expression. Shouldn't it be in the parentheses?

Comment: This is a perfect example of why you **shouldn't use a bare except** -- it hides a TypeError.

Comment: What would you prefer I use? This is the only type of exception handling I know of

Comment: @AndrewAlexander catch only the exceptions you expect to get (the *unexceptional* exceptions, you might say :D)

Comment: Kojiro, please answer the question so I can award you points.

Comment: @AndrewAlexander: You're doing too much inside your `try` block. Try to limit it to just the lines where you except to catch your error.

Comment: I'll award it as soon as SO lets me. Also, what are good IDE options for Python? When writing in PHP, I typically have these errors pointed out to me before even running.

Comment: It was going to pass all of the code though, if the try failed. Is there a way to set an if conditional based on the results of a try?

Comment: don't use string formatting to provide parameters for SQL. Use a placeholder such as `?`, `%s` depending on databse module and pass a tuple `(searchnumber,)` as the 2nd argument in `.execute()`.

Comment: @AndrewAlexander This probably isn't the best way to discuss good IDEs. As for your other question, if you can make it clearer, perhaps make it another proper SO question.

Answer (score 7):

You're probably hiding a `TypeError` because you're trying to use the `%` operator on whatever object or value is equivalent to `c.execute("string")`. You might've caught it if you hadn't hidden all errors with the bare except. You'll note this is a specific antipattern in the [official Python Dos and Don'ts page](http://docs.python.org/howto/doanddont.html#except).

Comment: +1, but I suggest editing your answer to say _how_ exceptions were hidden (with bare except)

Answer (score 5):

1. Never use `except: pass`, it hides information.
2. The information it's currently hiding is probably a failure from this code:

   ```
    c.execute("""SELECT words from searchterms where onstate = 1 AND progid = %d;""") % searchnumber
   ```